# write long hex to registry c#

Tags: c#, registry

i want to write long hex to registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore]
"Win32_AutoGameModeDefaultProfile"=hex:02,00,01,00,00,00,c4,20,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00
"Win32_GameModeRelatedProcesses"=hex:01,00,01,00,01,00,67,00,61,00,6d,00,65,00,\
  70,00,61,00,6e,00,65,00,6c,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00,c9,00,4e,95,67,\
  77,b0,eb,1e,03,d8,f1,1e,03,1e,00,00,00,b0,eb,1e,03,1e,00,00,00,0f,00,00,00,\
  2c,ea,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

i know how to write hex but not long:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile", "NetworkThrottlingIndex", 0xFFFFFFFF, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
```

how to write above long hex to registry in c#.

how to write above long hex to registry in c#.

Comment: Try a `byte[]` array maybe??

Comment: In your case, you want to write a QWord (64-bit integer) value. You can convert your hexadecimal value to a ulong and then use Registry.SetValue

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: `Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\.......", "SomeValue", yourByteArray, RegistryValueKind.Binary);`

Comment: thanks for example , but i mean how to convert that long hex to byte[]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: That's a completely different question, for which there are many duplicates.

Comment: i think that long hex text already in hex i not need to convert it , i need to prefix each number with 0x like this `byte[] b = { 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc4, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };` then write to registry as binary `Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore", "Win32_AutoGameModeDefaultProfile", b, RegistryValueKind.Binary);` this should work but i did not tested it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the long hex text already in hex i donot need to convert it , i need to prefix each number with 0x like this

```
byte[] b = { 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc4, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

then write to registry as binary

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore", "Win32_AutoGameModeDefaultProfile", b, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```

this was worked for me